# How to identify by what variable a dataset is grouped

Tags: r, group-by, dataset

I grouped my dataset and saved it without ungrouping it.
Then I loaded it and I no longer remember what variable was the grouping variable.
`class (mydata)` give:

```
"grouped_df" "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

By what operation can I identify the grouping variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `cur_group`

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% 
    group_by(cyl, am) %>% 
    summarise(out = names(cur_group()))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `group_vars` or `groups` -

```
library(dplyr)

res <- mtcars %>% group_by(cyl, am)

group_vars(res)
#[1] "cyl" "am" 

groups(res)
#[[1]]
#cyl

#[[2]]
#am
```